# How to get birthday date from today to this month end?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get customers birthday from today to this month end.

This is my table

```
id   dob           stid
1    1960-05-12    1389
2    1958-05-11    1389
3    1970-05-14    1389
4    1959-05-18    1389
```

and

```
function getBirthdayDate($date)
{
$dateqry='';    
if($date=='today')
{
$dateqry=" AND MONTH( `dob`) = '".date("m")."' AND DAY(`dob`)='".date("d")."'";
}
else if($date=='tomorrow')
{
$dateqry=" AND MONTH( `dob`) = '".date("m")."' AND DAY(`dob`)='".date("d", strtotime("+1 day"))."'";
}
else if($date=='month')
{
$dateqry=" AND MONTH( `dob`) = '".date("m")."' AND DAY(`dob`)='".date("d")."' BETWEEN DAY(`dob`)='".date("t")."' ";
}   
$sql="SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE store_id='1389' $dateqry ";
$result=dbQuery($sql);
return $row=$result->num_rows;
}
```

How can I get from today to this month end of last day?

**Note:** Here, year should not taken, only month and day. For example, this month and day between today and this month end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some HTML Form where you select whether to show the Birthdays for 'Today' or 'Tomorrow' or 'This Month' right?

Your conditions for 'Today' and 'Tomorrow' are right.

For the 'Month', change your condition as:

> ```
>    else if($date=='month')
>     {
>     $dateqry=" AND MONTH( `dob`) = '".date("m")."' AND DAY(`dob`) BETWEEN '".date("d")."' AND '".date("t")."' ";
>     }
> ```

ie, Use the BETWEEN clause for Today's Date and End of Month Date

Answer (score 1):

You can use date directly in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, mysql understands it well, so

for today to this month's end

```
$last_date = date('Y-m-t');
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$dateqry = " AND `dob` >= '$today' AND `dob` <= '$last_date'";
```

Comment: This will work for months with 31 days, otherwise, use `date('Y-m-t')`, which will return the *correct* number of days in any given month.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getBirthdayDate()
{
$dateqry='';    
$today=date("Y-m-d");
$lastdate=date("Y-m-t", strtotime($today));

$dateqry=" AND `dob`>= '".$today."' AND `dob`<='".$lastdate."'";

$sql="SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE store_id='1389' ".$dateqry." ";
$result=dbQuery($sql);
return $row=$result->num_rows;
}
```